# AccessControlException in doPriveledge

Tags: java, websphere-8, accesscontrolexception, java-security

We are trying to get the number of files from a directory using the below code:

```
   File dataDir = new File(dataHome);
            final File privdataDir = dataDir;
            System.out.println("The datadir is : \n"+dataDir+"The privdataDir is : \n"+privdataDir);
            int count = 0;
            final int[] privcount = {0};


            if (privdataDir != null) {
                System.out.println("Going into doPriveledge block");
            AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
                public Object run()
                {

                    privcount[0] = privdataDir.list().length;
                    return null;

                }
            });
            }

            count = privcount[0];
            System.out.println("The count is : "+count);
```

The dataDir variable refers to path : C:\MyApp\config
It is throwing AccessControlException at the following line in the code :

```
privcount[0] = privdataDir.list().length;
```

The exception is:

```
[ERROR][SmartlinkThread] 2015-03-18 07:22:59.0862 GMT: SmartlinkThread: Error processing agg interval: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\MyApp\config read) <AggIntervalTaskThread>
[ERROR][SmartlinkThread] 2015-03-18 07:22:59.0862 GMT: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\MyApp\config read) <AggIntervalTaskThread>
[ERROR][SmartlinkThread] 2015-03-18 07:22:59.0863 GMT:  at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:132) <AggIntervalTaskThread>
[ERROR][SmartlinkThread] 2015-03-18 07:22:59.0863 GMT:  at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544) <AggIntervalTaskThread>
[ERROR][SmartlinkThread] 2015-03-18 07:22:59.0863 GMT:  at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:883) <AggIntervalTaskThread>
[ERROR][SmartlinkThread] 2015-03-18 07:22:59.0863 GMT:  at java.io.File.list(File.java:982) <AggIntervalTaskThread>
```

The following has already been added to the java.policy file and server.policy file

```
grant codeBase "file:C:/MyApp/-" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

This code is being run for IBM Websphere 8.0.x.
In another part of the same application, it is giving the same error while reading a file.
We are not able to understand why the code is giving this error even though all the permissions have already been granted to it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting what had worked for me.

Our complete application does not deploy on Websphere. Only a part of it's code integrates with Websphere and collects some relevant data.
We believe some other web application which had been deployed on Websphere may have been enabling Java 2 Security.
Added the following statement to the server.policy and java.policy files:

```
grant{
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Please note that this grants permission to everything to do anything in Websphere.

Comment: Thats why I suggested to add it to the correct application via was.policy file, and not open it for whole server..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have web application that you deploy on WebSphere, and you have Java 2 Security enabled.

You should create in the `EAR/META-INF/was.policy` file, with the following content (your `codeBase` is incorrect):

```
grant codeBase "file:${application}" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

If you done that correctly, this file should be displayed during installation via web console.

For more details about creating policy files for WebSphere applications check [Configuring the was.policy file for Java 2 security](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tsec_waspolicyfile.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-12-2-7-3-0-1-0&lang=en)

Comment: The Java 2 Security is disabled.

Comment: @monvic If Java 2 Security is disabled, then you should not be having these errors. Are they from `SystemOut.log` as format looks strange. You can set `com.ibm.websphere.java2secman.norethrow=tue` JVM custom property to only log such kind of exceptions to see what privileges are needed.